# Spring Boot - logging configuration from JBoss

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, jboss, log4j

I'd like to know if there is a way to configure Spring Boot logging using JBoss standalone.xml or domain.xml configuration. For now I ended up with two empty files log4j.properties and log4j-file.properties under org\springframework\boot\logging\log4j package in mvn resources in WAR file and it looks like now my logging configuration in domain.xml works because I've overriden default spring-boot log4j configuration.

But there must be a better way to do this instead of this stupid hack. Keep in mind that I don't want to provide external log4j properties file and set it for one of the property in application.properties but I want to use jboss logging system configuration.

EDIT
Strange thing but when I updated Spring Boot to version 1.4.0 then JBoss intercepts the logs and log them only to the file and I don't have logs on the stdout anymore even without custom log4j configuration.